# Is there a name for this paragraph indentation style?

Tags: poetry, typography

In longer form poems you sometimes see a verse where the first line is indented to the level of the end of the previous verse’s last line. For example, [this Keats poem](https://archive.org/stream/completepoetical01keat#page/98/mode/2up):

[image: An image of a Keats poem showing the previously described effect]

or [this poem from Wordsworth](https://archive.org/stream/in.ernet.dli.2015.53574/2015.53574.Lyrical-Ballads#page/n193/mode/2up):

[image: An image of a Wordsworth poem showing the previously described effect]

Is there a name for this indentation style?

Comment: The reason, of course, is that a new sentence starts in the middle of a line of verse. You see the same thing in Shakespeare's plays, where a character's reply to another finishes a line of blank verse.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Robert Bringhurst, in his seminal work *The Elements of Typographic Style,* calls these ***dropline paragraphs,*** which is apt if rather prosaic.

[image: Scan of Bringhurst's description]

Answer (score 0):

[This website](http://learning.scribenet.com/node/2123) calls it the "Sli Indentation." I was only able to find this information from one source, so take it with a grain of salt.

Comment: Oh, cool, nice find. I’m going to leave this open for a couple more days as that’s quite a technical answer, but if no-one has any better suggestions I’ll accept this one.

Comment: "Sli" is something used in Scribe Markup Language (ScML) meaning "Senseline indent". This appears to be a term only used in ScML.